# Products related to category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm facing an issue to order products by price related to category. When I click "sort by price" it shows all products from all categories ordered by price. I need to present only the products that relate to the category that is in the url, ordering by price.
This is the controller:

```
class SortController extends MainController{

    public function sortBy($category_url, Request $request)
    {
        $sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');
        $products = Product::orderBy('price', $sort, $category_url)->get();
        return view('content.sort')->with('products', $products);
    }
}
```

This is the view:

```
extends('master')
@section ('content')

<form id="order-product-form" method="get" action=">>
    {{url('shop/{category_url}/sort=ASC')}}"enctype="multipart/form-data">
@if ($products) 
    @foreach($products as $product)
        {{ $product['title']}}
```

Comment: what is the value of `$category_url`. is it the category id?

Comment: the value is category_url

Comment: You say: the products that related to the cactegory that is in the url. where is this category?

Comment: I don't understand, tell me whatt u want to see

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need $category->products->title.

Do you have a relation between models Category and products?

Comment: Yes I have a relation between them

Answer (score 0):

To filter a model based on a related model you use `whereHas()`

```
$products = Product::whereHas('category', function ($query) {

    return $query->where('id', '=', $category_id); // You filter here by the required category
});

$products->orderBy('price', $sort, $category_url)->get();
```

Comment: I see, how can I combine it in my function?

Comment: Could you show me the controller where you return the view with all products?

Comment: this is the controller:class ShopController extends MainController
{
   public function categories(){
       
   self::$data['categories']=Categorie::all()->toArray();
   self::$data['title']=self::$data['title'].'| Shop Categories';

   return view('content.categories', self::$data);
   }
   
   public function products($category_url){
       
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    return view ('content.products', self::$data);
   }

Comment: the model:                                                   
class Product extends Model {   
    static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data){
        $data['products']=$data['category']=[];
        if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)->first()){
            $category= $category->toArray();
            $data['category']=$category;
            $data['title']=$data['title']. ' | ' . $category['title'];
            if ($products=Categorie::find( $category['id'])->products){   
                $data['products']= $products->toArray();
      }}}